# Add "see more" text when when UILabel get truncated inside table cell in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have news feed page kind of facebook. I wanted to add "see more" text to my UILabel(feed content) when its get truncated. I wanted to have action recognition on "see more" text too. These feed content are table cell. So when i tap on "see more" text cell height should also get adjusted according to content.

I have attach image for better clarification. Hope one of you guys will have a solution.

[image: See More feed card]

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the `UILabel.sizeThatFits()` is greater than your layout space.

Assuming your cell height is fixed, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, do the following

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Configure your cell
        let yourLabel : UILabel! //reference to the label which will truncate your text
        let neededSpace = yourLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: yourLabel.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        if neededSpace.height > yourLabel.frame.height {
            //Text will be truncated, show your button
        } else {
            //Text will be fully presented, hide the button
        }

        //your stuff

    }
```